# How provide Grid instead of Links on ModernWindow of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, modern-ui, mainwindow

On ModernWindow I have something like this for tabs:

```
<mui:Link DisplayName="Steps" Source="/Views/StepsControl.xaml" />
```

How could I have something like this:

```
 <mui:Link DisplayName="Steps"  >
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Content="Test"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </mui:Link>
```

Something like ControlTab, having content inside of each tab

The source Links:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Modern-UI-Samples-for-WPF-cfca7ddf

Answer (score 0):

You can't set any direct Content of a `Link` because it is not a `ContentControl`.

In fact, the `Link` type only has a `Source` and a `DisplayName` property that is inherited from the abstract `Displayable` base class. It's not some kind of `DependencyObject` so you should set the `Source` property to a XAML file where you define the `Grid`. You *cannot* define it inline.